# Integrating $e^{e^x+ax}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How am I able to integrate $e^{e^x+ax}$?

$$\int e^{e^x+ax} dx$$

Am I suppose to use $u$ substitution? But what should I let $x$ be? And what should $dx$ be?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Start by writing $e^{e^x+ax} = e^{e^x}\cdot e^{ax}$.

Comment: Are you sure you need to calculate an indefinite integral instead of a definite integral?

Comment: Double exponentials are uneasy (you won't find any in a basic table of antiderivatives), try to get rid of this one, using $u=e^x$.

Comment: indefinite integral

Comment: Indefinite isn't going to be easy. The substitution $e^x=t$ yields the following integral: 
$$\int e^t t^{a-1}\,dt$$
And this hasn't got an elementary antiderivate.

Comment: @Pranav You can create a series solution to this using integration by parts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By parts, $\int e^tt^{a-1} dt=e^tt^{a-1}-(a-1)\int e^tt^{a-2}dt=e^tt^{a-1}-(a-1)e^tt^{a-2}+(a-1)(a-2)\int e^tt^{a-3}dt=...$

You easily see the recurrence. When $a$ is a positive integer, develop until $t^0$.

Unfortunately, for negative integer $a$, integration by parts the other way
$\int e^tt^{a-1}dt=e^t\frac{t^a}a-\int e^t\frac{t^a}adt=e^t\frac{t^a}a-e^t\frac{t^{a+1}}{a(a+1)}+\int e^t\frac{t^{a+1}}{a(a+1)}dt=...$
leads to a dead-end with $t^{-1}$, i.e. $\int\frac{e^t}tdt$.

For arbitrary $a$, the primitive is related to the the incomplete Gamma function, with no closed formula.